# Required the field based on select option using jQuery Validation Engine library

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

The validationEngineLanguage function is to handle the custom requiredIf rule. It checks if the selected value is in the requiredValues array and ensures that the #desc field is not empty for the required values.

```js
(function($) {
  // Add custom rule for required fields based on selected value
  $.fn.validationEngineLanguage = function() {
    $.validationEngineLanguage.allRules.requiredIf = {
      "func": function(field, rules, i, options) {
        const fieldValue = field.val();
        const selectedValue = $(options.allrules.requiredIf.selectorValue).val();

        const requiredValues = options.allrules.requiredIf.requiredValues;

        if (requiredValues.includes(selectedValue)) {
          return fieldValue.trim() !== '';
        }

        return true;
      },
      "alertText": "* Field is required for the selected value."
    };
  };

  // Example usage
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myForm").validationEngine({
      custom_error_messages: {
        ".validate[requiredIf]": {
          "message": {
            "*": {
              "alertText": "* Field is required for the selected value."
            }
          }
        }
      },
      validationEventTrigger: "change"
    });

    $("#type").change(function() {
      $("#desc").validationEngine('validate');
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/validationEngine.jquery.min.css" integrity="sha512-fvBUZJJBrJrzrFYM/EN2isPokoNnx331y30ZXIxRRlop1aq6rT6d8oY6WJVsiXZoso0dIZ2nbQjtGLi6Kkxr/Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/jquery.validationEngine.min.js"></script>


<form id="myForm">
  <label for="type">Type:</label>
  <select id="type" class="validate[required]">
    <option value="">Select Type</option>
    <option value="AA">Type A</option>
    <option value="BB">Type B</option>
    <option value="CC">Type C</option>
    <option value="DD">Type D</option>
    <option value="XX">Type X</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <label for="desc">Description:</label>
  <input type="text" id="desc" class="validate[requiredIf[AA,XX],maxSize[10]]" />
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But it seems the rule doesn't work as expected. Any idea?